# How to express "since X" for an event that ended in the past?

Tags: tense, time, time-reference

> She has been the CEO since 2000

A [question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556997/is-head-of-xyz-since-vs-has-been-since-is-is-ever-acceptable) explores the matter of present vs. past tense in the context of the usage of "since". The conclusions that it is much better to use the past tense.

With this in mind, how can I express the difference between

- She has been the CEO since 2000 and stopped to be so at some point between 2000 and today
- She has been the CEO since 2000 and still is the CEO today

without going verbose on the dates?

Comment: She was the CEO from 2000 until sometime later.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: ah, so would  *she was the CEO since 2000* be correct then? And express the fact that she was the CEO in 2000, and is no more today (which implies that she stopped to be someone in between?)

Comment: No. My sentence conveys when she became CEO and the fact that she is not any more. You don't need 'since'. She was (simple past) the CEO for a time (from 2000 until an unspecified date).

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from using *has been*.  Remember that *has* is a **present** tense, so if she's not CEO anymore, you can't use it!